# Centering images on rails with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center and enlarge these two images by setting up a class then editing in stylesheets/scss but am having no luck.  This is the html code:

```
<div class="row" class="testimoinal_image">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <%= link_to image_tag("south_london.jpg", class:"south_london")%>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <%= link_to image_tag("statravellogo.jpg", class:"statravellogo"), "https://http://www.statravel.co.uk/", :target => "_blank"%>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is what I'm trying to do in the stylesheet - .south_london class seems to let me change the size but not the position, .statravellogo class will not respond to any changes:

```
.testimonial_image{
max-width: 15rem;
text-align: center;
}

.south_london{
    max-width: 20rem;
    float: center;
}

.statravellogo{
    max-width: 15rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Would love to hear any thoughts

Comment: What HTML does Rails output for this: `<%= link_to image_tag("south_london.jpg", class:"south_london")%>`?

Comment: `float: center` isn't valid, you misspelled `.testimonial_image` in your markup/html, and you just need to either fix `.testimonial_image` so `text-align: center` works, or add the class `text-center` to the `.col` elements that wrap the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael Coker says, the property float: center; isn't valid

As you use bootstrap, you can use the offsets of the bootstrap grid to place your two images in the center of the page

This HTML5 code :

```
<div class="row" class="testimoinal_image">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-4">
       <%= link_to image_tag("south_london.jpg", class:"south_london")%> -->
       <%= link_to image_tag("statravellogo.jpg", class:"statravellogo"), "https://http://www.statravel.co.uk/", :target => "_blank"%>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-4"></div>
</div>
```

And the code CSS :

```
.testimonial_image{
    text-align: center;
    }

    .south_london{
        max-width: 20rem;
    }

    .statravellogo{
        max-width: 15rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
```